# Set / Link point and shape options for variables in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to link variables I have in a dataframe i.e. (`'prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3'`) to specific colours and shapes in the plot. However, I also want to exclude data (using `dplyr::filter`) to customise the plot display WITHOUT changing the points and shapes used for a specific variable. A minimal example is given below.

```
  library(ggplot2)
  library(dplyr)
  library(magrittr)

obj <- c("cmpd 1","cmpd 1","cmpd 1","cmpd 2","cmpd 2")
  x <- c(1, 2, 4, 7, 3)
  var <- c("prop1","prop2","prop3","prop2","prop3")
  y <- c(1, 2, 3, 2.5, 4)
  col <- c("#E69F00","#9E0142","#56B4E9","#9E0142","#56B4E9")
  shp <- c(0,1,2,1,2)
  df2 <- cbind.data.frame(obj,x,var,y,col,shp)

  plot <- ggplot(data = df2 %>%
                       filter(obj %in% c(
                         "cmpd 1",
                         "cmpd 2"
                       )),
                     aes(x = x,
                         y = y,
                         colour = as.factor(var), 
                         shape = as.factor(var))) +  
    geom_point(size=2) + 
    #scale_shape_manual(values=shp) +
    #scale_color_manual(values=col) + 
    facet_grid(.~obj) 
  plot
```

[image: plot1]

However, when I redact `cmpd1` (just hashing in code) the colour and shape of `prop2` and `prop3` for `cmpd2` change (please see plot2).
[image: plot2]

To this end, I tried adding in `scale_shape_manual` and `scale_color_manual` to the code (currently hashed) and linked these to specific vars (`col` and `shp`) in the dataframe (`df2`), but the same problem arises that both the shape and color of these variables changes when excluding one of the conditions?

Any and all help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
obj <- c("cmpd 1","cmpd 1","cmpd 1","cmpd 2","cmpd 2")
x <- c(1, 2, 4, 7, 3)
var <- c("prop1","prop2","prop3","prop2","prop3")
y <- c(1, 2, 3, 2.5, 4)

df2 <- cbind.data.frame(obj,x,var,y)
col <- c("prop1" = "#E69F00", 
         "prop2" = "#9E0142",
         "prop3" = "#56B4E9")
shp <- c("prop1" = 0, 
         "prop2" = 1,
         "prop3" = 2)

plot <- ggplot(data = df2 %>%
                 filter(obj %in% c(
                   "cmpd 1",
                   "cmpd 2"
                 )),
               aes(x = x,
                   y = y,
                   colour = var, 
                   shape = var)) +  
  geom_point(size=2) + 
  scale_shape_manual(values=shp) +
  scale_color_manual(values=col) + 
  facet_grid(.~obj) 
plot
```

Comment: Hi Zhiqiang. Thanks very much for the rapid response, works perfectly ;-)